# Fluent NHibernate One-To-One -> One-To-Many Relationship

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I wonder if anyone can help. I have a parent/child relationship where the parent has a one-to-one relationship to the child, but the child can have many parents.

Parent Mapping:

```
public sealed class DatumMap : ClassMap<Datum>
{
    public DatumMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.DataValue);
        References(x => x.MergeField).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Child Mapping:

```
public sealed class MergeFieldMap : ClassMap<MergeField>
{
    public MergeFieldMap()
    {
        ReadOnly();
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.MergeTag);
        HasMany(x => x.Data);
    }
}
```

If I create two new detached parents with new identical children, and then save them one after another, I will persist two "copies" of the child rather then reusing the existing child entity.

I can force reuse of the child class if it exists by looking it up and attaching it to the 2nd parent.

I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to achieve this so that if I try and persist what is essentially the same child entity, it uses the existing entity otherwise it creates a new child.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the lookup if the child already exists has to be performed somehow. However which two children are identical is business logic which differs hence it will not happen out of the box.

```
// code to save new Parent

Child child = ...

var parent = new Parent { Child = child };

session.Save(parent);
```

If identical means Id (assuming GeneratedBy Assigned) then

```
Child child = session.Get<Child>(childId);
if (child == null)
    child = new Child(childId);
```

if you know the child already exists

```
// will generate a proxy instead of querying
Child child = session.Get<Child>(childId);
```

if identical means a natural id/key

```
Child child = session.Query<Child>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.UniqueProperty == uniqueProperty);
if (child == null)
    child = new Child(childId);
```